# Type mismatch: cannot convert from KeyCode to KeyCode

Tags: java

So I am having a bit of a strange situation with type mismatching.  General idea is that I am creating a game in which the player will be able to define their own keybinds for moving, buttons etc.

I have started out with a standard key event listener which is then feeding into a key handler

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

// Key event single key
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
                btnHand.keyPressHandler(key.getCode());
        }
    });

import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public void keyPressHandler(KeyCode keyCode) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case GameOptions.getMoveNorth():    //method call           break;
    case GameOptions.getMoveSouth():    //method call           break;
    case GameOptions.getMoveWest():     //method call           break;
    case GameOptions.getMoveEast():     //method call           break;


    default:    System.out.println("key : " + keyCode + " was pressed, yet has no handler");
    }
}
```

I plan to store the keybindings in an options class called GameOptions which is holding my keybindings as such and using getters to pull the key info I need

```
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class GameOptions {

private static KeyCode moveNorth;
private static KeyCode moveEast;
private static KeyCode moveSouth;
private static KeyCode moveWest;

public GameOptions() {}

    public static KeyCode getMoveNorth() {
        return moveNorth;
    }
```

But I am now at a loss as to why it is causing a type mismatch as to my eyes they are the same type.  Pointers to lead me in the right direction would be nice

Comment: I would recommend not to use methods in switch statements. Create a key - action map and only work with the actions.

Comment: In other news, it's possible to bind to a key.

Comment: Can you include the full set of `import` statements from the top of each class file here, as well as the *exact* compiler error you are receiving?

Comment: @JasonC added import statements.  The error message is on the method calls within my switch, and the error is exactly the same as the title, the suugested fixes are adding a cast to KeyCode, or changing the return type of the getter to KeyCode

Comment: @kaetzacoatl For curiosities sake, why is it not good to use methods in switch statements?

Comment: @Fluke It's not that it isn't good, it's that it [won't compile](http://ideone.com/NziDRS). Case expressions must be constant, it's part of the language spec. "Recommend" was an understatement. Anyways what is the exact compiler error and which line is it pointing to?

Comment: @JasonC The error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from KeyCode to KeyCode". I then tried taking the method call out of the switch statement, assigning the method to a variable and then using that in the switch.  That then gives the error "cannot be resolved or is not a field".  I think the problem is that I am running into the problem that you mention about case statements being constant.  I may have to look into other options about how to handle this.

Comment: @Fluke Wait. I'm sure my answer is *a* problem but I'm not 100% convinced it's the source of your error messages, which don't match what I describe. When you get "cannot be resolved or is not a field", *what* does it say can't be resolved? In any event, as for the case labels, you are correct, variables won't work either. The labels must be constant expressions or enum names.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I'm sure this answer identifies a problem but I'm not at all convinced it's the source of the precise error messages you identify, which don't really match the error you'd receive for non-constant `case` labels. Will update with clarification, will leave this here for now as-is.*

While the errors are rather cryptic the fundamental problem is that `case` only accepts [constant expressions and enum constant names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11), method calls and variables are not acceptable. Working within your current architecture the most straightforward way is to simply use an `if` instead, as there is no reason you *must* use a `switch`:

```
public void keyPressHandler(KeyCode keyCode) {
    if (keyCode == GameOptions.getMoveNorth()) {
        ...
    } else if (keyCode == GameOptions.getMoveSouth()) {
        ...
    } else if (keyCode == GameOptions.getMoveWest()) {
        ...
    } else if (keyCode == GameOptions.getMoveEast()) {
        ...
    } else {
        System.out.println("key : " + keyCode + " was pressed, yet has no handler");    
    }
}
```

For completeness, if you *did* insist on using a `switch` there, the labels would have to be constants, so your only option would be to move the key code translation elsewhere, e.g. (the choice to make `Action` a member of `GameOptions` is just to keep this example simple):

```
class GameOptions {

    enum Action {
        MOVE_NORTH,
        MOVE_SOUTH,
        MOVE_WEST,
        MOVE_EAST
    }; 

    // returns null if unmapped, or you could use an Action.NO_ACTION or something.
    public static Action getActionFromKeyCode (KeyCode keyCode) {
        ...
    }

}
```

And then your handler becomes:

```
public void keyPressHandler(KeyCode keyCode) {
    switch (GameOptions.getActionFromKeyCode(keyCode)) {
    case GameOptions.Action.MOVE_NORTH: ...; break;
    case GameOptions.Action.MOVE_SOUTH: ...; break;
    case GameOptions.Action.MOVE_WEST: ...; break;
    case GameOptions.Action.MOVE_EAST: ...; break;
    default: ...; break;
    }
}
```

However, that approach has some caveats:

- It implies that `GameOptions` must be aware of *all* key bindings, else the `keyPressHandler` becomes more complicated.
- It moves some of your UI logic out of your UI and into `GameOptions`, which is architecturally weird in some situations, and can be problematic in more complex scenarios.
- It doesn't gain you much over the `if` approach, it's a lot more verbose for no real benefit here. And anyways you still have the matter of implementing that same big `if` in `getActionFromKeyCode`, same as your original issue, just moved to a different place.

Not the best option for you but wanted to put it out there as a concept to think about. I'd just go with the `if`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think for the meanwhile I may move over to an if approach to get things actually working.  However I am also going to have a look at learning about inputmap/actionmaps as that seems to be a more "expandable" solution that having what could be a huge if statement

Comment: @Fluke ActionMaps/InputMaps would be the most appropriate way to go in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of what I had before and using the idea of mapping I have come to a nice conclusion.  It will do for the moment I feel, it may fall over in the future...who knows....onto the next new thing!!

```
public void keyPressHandler(KeyCode keyCode) {

    HashMap<KeyCode, String> kmap = new HashMap<KeyCode, String>();

    kmap.put(GameOptions.getMoveNorth(), "north");
    kmap.put(GameOptions.getMoveEast(), "east");
    kmap.put(GameOptions.getMoveSouth(), "south");
    kmap.put(GameOptions.getMoveWest(), "west");

    String kact = kmap.get(keyCode);

    if (kact == null) {
        kact = "";
    }

    switch(kact) {
    case "north":
        northButtonHandler();
        break;
    case "east":
        eastButtonHandler();
        break;
    case "south":
        southButtonHandler();
        break;
    case "west":
        westButtonHandler();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("key : " + keyCode + " has been pressed, yet has no binding");
    }
}
```